# Make vimeo or youtube play on modal open and stop video play on modal close

Tags: javascript, youtube, modal-dialog

I have done test page on following url http://www.air8cushion.com/index.php/popup-test/ and I created custom modal window that opens when you click on Video play button inside that big banner. Inside modal window I inserted Vimeo video. Now what I need is that once modal window opens up, that video starts playing automatically and once I close it using "CLOSE" button that video stops playing.

Is something like that possible to do with my example and are there any sample codes I can use for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at a library to control your vidéo, for vimeo i don't know but i recently used the youtube iframe api library https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

You should get there with the example.